# Custom Action Bar icon behavior

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

How can I attach custom listener to Action Bar icon or title? Is it possible to set custom behavior to overflow menu? I'm using Action Bar Sherlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a customNavigationLayout. In that layout you can create your own buttons etc and attach listeners to them the way you want.